# Anonymous site with Form Based Authentication is showing login page

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, anonymous-authentication

I have a site with Anonymous access and Form Based authentication enabled.

When a user opens website (site page for e.g. about us, contact us), it shows that screen where user has to choose whether to select Windows Authentication or Form Based Authentication. Is there a way so this screen is not shown and user goes straight to site page?

Anonymous access is already enabled so it should not ask for authentication.

Comment: is anonymous enabled at web app level as well  site collection level for complete content?

Comment: Yes. And the page on which SharePoint is asking me to choose authentication type is Application page. If I access my site's home page which is normal site page then it doesn't ask.

Comment: FIxed it by inheriting my application page from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase class. Previously I was inheriting from LayoutsPageBase class.